# app route - not redirecting to html page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

This is a sample from MEAN stack website, 
I require the browser to point to a html file called ' findCable.html ' 
instead it keeps routing it to 'singleCable.html' 
The code snippet is from angular routing file, I've also checked the  back-end route(s) any ideas what's going wrong ?

Please see the attached images too _ TIA

```
   .when('/cable/search', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/pages/cables/findCable.html',
        controller: 'cableController',
        controllerAs: 'cable'
    })
```

[Screenshot of website code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZvmN.jpg)

Comment: may be `cable/:cable_id` and `cable/search` collide

Comment: tnx, that was the issue :) But why does this happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple routing mistake.
Just keep your `cable/search` route above the `cable/:cable_id` route which is overriding your `search` keyword as `cable_id`

Comment: Thank you, is there any particular topic i can read to understand and avoid this error ?

Comment: I think any router uses matching algorithms or regex to match their routes. Nothing to learn somewhere, just order your routes by keeping regex in mind. Write specific routes before the generic routes.